# LINQ on Datatable Find where all rows are empty

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a code reading data from excel spreadsheet and I have gone this far with some answers on SO

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where((row, index) => index > 4).CopyToDataTable();
DataTable filteredRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row.ItemArray.All(field => !(field is System.DBNull))).CopyToDataTable();
```

having this

```
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row.ItemArray.All(field => (field is System.DBNull)))
```

returns all rows that are empty.

I have also tried `Any`, it didn't give the required output

The code above works for where all the fields are not NULL i.e. every columns has a field. This exempt all rows that have 1 column missing but that's not what I want.

I want to exempt all rows that have all columns empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the NOT (`!`) out one level.  You want the items where "all rows are null" is not true, rather than where "all of the rows are not null" is true.

```
DataTable filteredRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(field => field is System.DBNull))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried filtering to Any Field instead of All?

```
DataTable filteredRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row.ItemArray.Any(field => !(field is System.DBNull))).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: have you tried this code?  It looks like it should work.  Mine is the same, logically, due to DeMorgan's law, but my answer is a more literal translation of your English statement to conditional logic so it might be easier for you to read.